# Avast and AVG reported virus in my app - Android: Evo-gen [Trj]

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-play-console, antivirus, virus

In the mobile application I developed with flutter 5 months ago, I started to scan for viruses in recent weeks based on user comments. I've scanned with more than 10 antiviruses (Malwarebytes, Kaspersky etc) and only Avast and AVG, products from the same company, found viruses. So I contacted Google and they asked me to update the app to scan for viruses. And again no virus found in the app.

**VirusTotal Results**
[image]

However, when AVG and Avast are installed on the phone, when you download the application from the play store, it gives a trojan notification.

[image]

The app got a very low rating because of users' reviews that it's a virus. Is there a way to report this company and fix this situation? Reporting that an app downloaded from the Play Store is infected is a loss of trust for Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it is a false positive, You can report a suspected False Positive  [here](https://www.avast.com/false-positive-file-form.php).

Comment: Yeah I already sent it but they don't care. I've seen dozens of apps labeled as infected because of Avast.